# empty paginate object sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pagination, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy to retrieve a list of objects using the paginate function

```
results = models.Object.query.filter(models.Object.id.in_(list_of_ids)).paginate(page, 10, False)
```

Sometimes `list_of_ids` can be empty. I noticed that queries where this list is empty are very slow. There is also a warning telling me that querying empty lists can be slow. However, to keep my functionality simple I need an empty paginate object. Is there a way to get that without running a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably mess around and instantiate your own instance of an empty `Pagination` object in order to avoid a query, but it might just be easier to perform a simple, fast, query that returns no rows:

```
>>> empty_paginator = models.Object.query.filter_by(id=None).paginate()
>>> empty_paginator.items
[]
>>> empty_paginator.has_next
False
```

The query should be very fast as it is on the table's primary key and will therefore use an index. Just make sure that you select something that doesn't exist, e.g. an id of `None`. Then use it like this:

```
if list_of_ids:
    results = models.Object.query.filter(models.Object.id.in_(list_of_ids)).paginate(page, 10, False)
else:
    results = models.Object.query.filter_by(id=-1).paginate()
```

Another way would be to subclass a `Pagination` object, overriding the methods that require a valid query object in order to avoid making a query:

```
class EmptyPaginator(flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EmptyPaginator, self).__init__(None, 1, 1, 0, [])

    def next(self, error_out=False):
        self.page += 1
        return self

    def prev(self, error_out=False):
        self.page -= 1
        return self
```

Use it like this:

```
if list_of_ids:
    results = models.Object.query.filter(models.Object.id.in_(list_of_ids)).paginate(page, 10, False)
else:
    results = EmptyPaginator()
```

or this (more succinct but less readable):

```
results = models.Object.query.filter(models.Object.id.in_(list_of_ids)).paginate(page, 10, False) if list_of_ids else EmptyPaginator()
```